# Why can't I load Safe App in an iframe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am working on an app that helps with composing multiple contracts, https://sobol.io/d/labs/hats_composer. I am using the Safe APIs to create new safes but I am using iframes of the Safe App to show the user the contract after it is deployed. The iframes were working but in the past few weeks have stopped working and display the following message "app.safe.global refused to connect." Is this a Safe bug? Has Safe stopped supporting iframes? Trying to figure out how to move forward.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Loading the safe app in a frame **will not work**, as the response contains in **HTTP Header**

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

That means, the browser won't display it in the iframe on another domain.

Comment: Thanks @tenbits.

Does anyone know why Safe has chosen to restrict loading Safe app in a frame? Is this a new policy made by the Safe team?

Comment: Actually, it is a common practice to apply anti-iframe protection to protect users, so I am wondering why they haven't implemented this earlier.

Comment: I didn't realize that was the case, I just assumed they were pro iframe because many of the apps in their marketplace utilize iframing (were we got the idea to iframe to save effort). 
Out of curiosity do you know if the attack vector is the sign in process in the iframe?